# Find the Number of even intergers in a sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

enter an arbitrary sequence of integers at the keyboard, and then prints the number of positive even integers user enters.

```
def find_even_count():
          count = 0
          x = raw_input("Enter a value, or q to quit: ")
          while (x != "q") and (x > 0):
              for num in x:
                  if (int(x) % 2 == 0):
                      count += 1
                      entry = raw_input("Enter a value, or q to quit: ")
          return count
```

I have gotten this so far but it is not working any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what the input will be. Your code says one thing and your question another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are counting them as they are entered there is no need to iterate.

```
def find_even_count():
    count = 0
    x = raw_input("Enter a value, or q to quit: ")
    while (x != "q") and (x > 0):
        if (int(x) % 2 == 0):
            count += 1
        x = raw_input("Enter a value, or q to quit: ")
    return count
```

on the other hand if you had a sequence of numbers getting the number of evens is O(n) and can be written one pythonic line.

```
numberOfEvens = sum([1 if k%2==0 else 0 for k in sequence])
```

Comment: This is wrong. Integers are defined as the numbers which can be written without a fractional component. `-1000` is an integer. You should not have `x > 0` in the `while` loop, since it'll cause it to break for negatives.

Comment: @royhowie OP said *number of positive even integers*

Comment: @Michael so only count the positive even integers: `if (int(x) > 0 && int(x) % 2 == 0):`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is You are getting wrong input, in the Loop, You are Using different variable for second Input. Just change the Variable name inside the Loop as `x` there You Go.

```
def find_even_count():
count = 0
x = raw_input("Enter a value, or q to quit: ")
while (x != "q") and (int(x) > 0):
    if (int(x) % 2 == 0):
        count += 1
    x = raw_input("Enter a value, or q to quit: ")
return count
```

Comment: See my comment on kpie's answer; `int(x) > 0` is not necessary. The OP said the input would be integers, not positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line `entry = raw_input("Enter a value, or q to quit: ")` might be causing issues. if you noticed, in kpie's code, the line is inline with the `if` statement. in your code it will only be executed if `x` is even. if `x` is odd, your code will loop forever. additionally, `entry` is never used, so, again, `x` won't change.